# Create a zip consisting of multiple fileoutputStreams objects

Tags: apache-poi, fileoutputstream, zipoutputstream

I have a method in which in a loop I am creating `FileOutputStream` objects of excel files. Each file is in different folder as per the requirement. I need to create a zip response as well of the whole. Is there a way to add those fileoutputstream objects in the zipoutputstream( in the same loop, while the files are getting generated)?

Consider this as pseudo code

```java
// For Loop creating Fileoutputstream
{
try (FileoutPutStream fileOut= new FileoutputStream(FilePath);
   workbook.write(fileOut);
   workbook.close();
///**add logic to add this file into zip.**
}
```

I have tried creating a zipoutputstream object and writing the content into the zip.entry() but it did not work. Plus i am confused as if this is possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ZipFile and add them like this. `file` is an object of class `File`. `ZipFile` is imported from `import net.lingala.zip4j.ZipFile;`.

```java
      try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("compressed.zip")) {
            zipFile.addFile(file, zipParameters);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error during zipping of file");
            throw e;
        }
```

where `zipParameters` are

```java
ZipParameters zipParameters = new ZipParameters();
zipParameters.setCompressionLevel(CompressionLevel.NORMAL);
```

Comment: Unfortunately i dont have this dependency in the project. If possible please tell me just using Java and apache poi libraries.